# Php search function error when i search with multiple results and even if theres no records found

Tags: php

OK i have this code:

plain html(index.html):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form" action="search.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="q" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this search function php file(search.php):

```
<?php  // Get the search variable from URL
if(!isset($_GET['q']))
die("Search Query not found"); 
$var = $_GET['q'];
$trimmed = trim($var); //trim whitespace from the stored variable

// rows to return
$limit=10;

// check for an empty string and display a message.
if ($trimmed == ""){
echo "<p>Please enter a search…</p>";
exit;
}

// check for a search parameter
if (!isset($var)){
echo "<p>We dont seem to have a search parameter!</p>";
exit;
}

//connect to your database ** EDIT REQUIRED HERE **
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

//specify database ** EDIT REQUIRED HERE **
mysql_select_db("sakila") or die("Unable to select database");
// Build SQL Query
$query = "select * from customer where first_name like \"%$trimmed%\" or last_name like     \"%$trimmed%\" or email like \"%$trimmed%\" order by first_name DESC";

// EDIT HERE and specify your table and field names for the SQL query

$numresults=mysql_query($query);
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($numresults);

// If we have no results, offer a google search as an alternative — this is optional

if ($numrows == 0)
{
echo "<h4>Results</h4>";
echo "<p>Sorry, your search: $trimmed returned zero results</p>";

// google
echo "<p><a href=\"http://www.google.com/search?q="
. $trimmed . "\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Look up
" . $trimmed . " on Google\">Click here</a> to try the
search on google</p>";
}

// next determine if s has been passed to script, if not use ZERO (0) to Limit the     output
if (empty($s)) {
$s=0;
}

// get results
$query .= " limit $s,$limit";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Couldn’t execute query");

// display what the person searched for
echo "<p>You searched for: $var </p>";

// begin to show results set
echo "Results: <br/>";
$count = 1 + $s ;

// now you can display the results returned
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$f_name = $row["first_name"];
$l_name = $row["last_name"];
$email = $row["email"];

echo "$count.> $f_name $l_name $email<br/>" ;
$count++ ;
}

$currPage = (($s/$limit) + 1);

//break before paging
echo "<br />";

// next we need to do the links to other results
if ($s>=1) {

// bypass PREV link if s is 0
$prevs=($s-$limit);
print " <a href=\"$PHP_SELF?s=$prevs&q=$var\"><<
Prev 10</a>  ";
}

// calculate number of pages needing links
$pages=intval($numrows/$limit);

// $pages now contains int of pages needed unless there is a remainder from division

if ($numrows%$limit) {
// has remainder so add one page
$pages++;
}

// check to see if last page
if (!((($s+$limit)/$limit)==$pages) && $pages!=1) {

// not last page so give NEXT link
$news=$s+$limit;

echo " <a href=\"$PHP_SELF?s=$news&q=$var\">Next 10 >></a>";
}

$a = $s + ($limit) ;
if ($a > $numrows) { $a = $numrows ; }
$b = $s + 1 ;
echo "<p>Showing results $b to $a of $numrows</p>";

?>
```

and i got this error: "Notice: Undefined variable: PHP_SELF in C:\xampp\htdocs\search\search.php on line 105" and this is the line 105: "echo " Next 10 >>";", whenever I search on it with a multiple result and even if no record was found. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> "Notice: Undefined variable: PHP_SELF in C:\xampp\htdocs\search\search.php on line 105"

Change `$PHP_SELF` to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Comment: I tried it and i got this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\search\search.php on line 105"